# Swiper doesn't snap to next slide correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) to create slides that link images and text.
I want:
[image: I want to do like this]

**Problem**

The slide numbers of img and text don't match.
I know there is a problem with the number of slides in the text. Because img slides work fine if I remove the controller for link.
I also know that the cause of the mismatch is `slidesPerView === auto`.

**What I tried**

After looking at a lot of code, I thought this was the cause. (I'm sorry if it was a mistake)
L4849 of swiper-bundle.js

```
_proto.slidesPerViewDynamic = function slidesPerViewDynamic() {   // This is used when slidesPerView === auto
  var swiper = this;
  var params = swiper.params,
      slides = swiper.slides,
      slidesGrid = swiper.slidesGrid,
      swiperSize = swiper.size,
      activeIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
  var spv = 1;

  if (params.centeredSlides) {
    var slideSize = slides[activeIndex].swiperSlideSize;
    var breakLoop;

    for (var i = activeIndex + 1; i < slides.length; i += 1) {
      if (slides[i] && !breakLoop) {
        slideSize += slides[i].swiperSlideSize;
        spv += 1;
        if (slideSize > swiperSize) breakLoop = true;
      }
    }

    for (var _i = activeIndex - 1; _i >= 0; _i -= 1) {
      if (slides[_i] && !breakLoop) {
        slideSize += slides[_i].swiperSlideSize;
        spv += 1;
        if (slideSize > swiperSize) breakLoop = true;
      }
    }
  } else {
    // ↓ this..?
    for (var _i2 = activeIndex + 1; _i2 < slides.length; _i2 += 1) {
      if (slidesGrid[_i2] - slidesGrid[activeIndex] < swiperSize) {
        spv += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return spv;
};
```

I thought that `snapGrid` or `slidesGrid` or `slides.length` in swiper-bundle.js may not be obtained properly.
However, I couldn't solve it because I didn't know how to debug it.

Would you please lend me a hand?
Thanks in advance.

**My problem code**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/Lqd7r629/21/)

```js
var swiperImgs = new Swiper('.swiper-imgs', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  autoHeight: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    clickable: 'true',
  },
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
  },
  renderBullet: function(index, className) {
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
  },
});

var swiperTexts = new Swiper('.swiper-texts', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    clickable: 'true',
  },
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
  },
  renderBullet: function(index, className) {
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
  },
  controller: {
    control: swiperImgs,
    by: 'slide',
  },
});

swiperImgs.controller.control = swiperTexts;
swiperImgs.controller.by = 'slide';
```

```css
/* The corresponding part is at the bottom too. (It is faster to count from the bottom)
(There is a mark in the comment) */

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #c6d2dd;
  color: white;
}

#wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1.8rem 4.7rem 2.7rem 2.4rem;
}

h1,
p {
  line-height: 1.8;
}

h1::before,
h1::after,
p::before,
p::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

h1::before,
p::before {
  margin-bottom: calc(-0.3125em + 0px);
}

h1::after,
p::after {
  margin-top: calc(-0.4375em + 0px);
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  display: inline;
}

.mission,
.m-p,
.concept,
.c-p,
.what,
.target,
.t-p,
.main-p,
.nb,
.nb-p,
.period,
.p-p,
.category,
.cg-p,
.class,
.cl-p,
.release,
.r-p,
.nbb,
.per,
.cat,
.cla,
.rel {
  display: inline-block;
}

#left,
#right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#left {
  width: 57%;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  width: 43%;
  padding-left: 6.5rem;
}

.title {
  height: 3.55rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
}

.solid-ti {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: .1rem solid white;
  margin-top: 5.35rem;
}

.solid-mc {
  border-bottom: .1rem solid white;
  margin-left: -2.4rem;
}

.solid-tm {
  border-bottom: .1rem solid white;
  margin-right: -4.7rem;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  top: 6rem;
}

.max {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.max-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-imgs .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.swiper-imgs .swiper-slide img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  opacity: .3;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet::before {
  content: '0';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet:hover::before {
  content: '1';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: none;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: .16s;
  opacity: .7;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active::before {
  content: '1';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mis {
  padding: 2.6rem 0 0.7rem 0;
}

.mission {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.con {
  padding-top: 0.7rem;
}

.concept {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.what {
  margin: 2rem 1.5rem 0 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.what>img {
  height: 2rem;
  margin-right: .3rem;
}

.what>img:last-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.what span {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border: .1rem solid white;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem .4rem .4rem;
}

.tar {
  padding: 2.2rem 0 2rem 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.target {
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
}

.t-p {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.heartbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.heartbox div:last-child {
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1, 1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.75, 1);
  }

  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.15, 1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 0.85, 1);
  }

  65% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
  }

  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.heart {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  fill: #E2E2E2;
}

#fav:checked+label .heart {
  fill: #e23b3b;
  animation: rubberBand 0.8s;
}



/*
 * from here
 */
 
.mai {
  margin: 2.8rem 0 0 0;
  height: 37.8rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.mai::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.main-p p {
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-bottom: 2.7rem;
  height: auto;
}

.main-p .swiper-slide-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*
 * to here
 */



.▼ {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin: 1.3rem 1.5rem 7.9625rem 0;
}

.R-under {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.nbb {
  padding-right: 4.8rem;
}

.nb {
  padding-right: .8rem;
}

.period {
  padding-right: 1.6rem;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: .3rem 0 2rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.cg-p,
.cl-p,
.r-p {
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.2.0/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.2.0/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The corresponding part is at the bottom. (It is faster to count from the bottom)
(There is a mark in the comment) -->

<body>
  <div class="solid-ti"></div>

  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>

      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <div class="swiper-container swiper-imgs max">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper imgs max-inner">
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/1920a6/ffffff/693x350.png?text=1" alt="1" /></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/199fa6/ffffff/693x350.png?text=2" alt="2" /></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/a61972/ffffff/693x350.png?text=3" alt="3" /></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/a6a619/ffffff/693x350.png?text=4" alt="4" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="L-under">
        <div class="mis">
          <h3 class="mission">sample</h3>
          <p class="m-p">samplesamplesamplesample</p>
        </div>

        <div class="solid-mc"></div>

        <div class="con">
          <h2 class="concept">sample</h2>
          <p class="c-p">samplesamplesamplesample</p>
        </div>

        <div class="what">
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/28x20.png?text=_" alt="2nd" /><img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/20x20.png?text=_" alt="ai" /><img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/20x20.png?text=_" alt="vw" />

          <span>sample</span>
          <span>sample</span>
          <span>sample</span>
          <span>sample</span>
          <span>sample</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="cat">
          <h5 class="category">sample</h5>
          <p class="cg-p">sample</p>
        </div>

        <div class="cla">
          <h5 class="class">sample</h5>
          <p class="cl-p">sample</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rel">
          <h5 class="release">sample</h5>
          <p class="r-p">sample</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="heartbox">
        <div class="tar">
          <h3 class="target">sample</h3>
          <p class="t-p">sample<br>
            samplesamplesample<br>
            samplesamplesample</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="fav" id="fav">
          <label for="fav">
            <svg class="heart" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 37 32"
              style="enable-background:new 0 0 37 32;" xml:space="preserve">
              <path class="st0" d="M27,0c-2.5,0-4.9,0.9-6.7,2.6C19.6,3.2,19,4,18.5,4.7C18,4,17.4,3.2,16.7,2.6C14.9,0.9,12.5,0,10,0
            C4.5,0,0,4.5,0,10c0,3.7,1.2,6.7,3.9,9.8c3.9,4.6,13.9,11.6,14.3,11.9c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1s0.2,0,0.3-0.1
            c0.4-0.3,10.4-7.3,14.3-11.9c2.7-3.2,3.9-6.1,3.9-9.8C37,4.5,32.5,0,27,0z" /></svg>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="solid-tm"></div>





    <!--
from here
-->
      <div class="mai max swiper-texts">
        <section class="main-p max-inner swiper-wrapper">
          <p class="swiper-slide">Please scroll here! (You can also scroll the img part) samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample<br>samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample<br>samplesamplesamplesamplesample</p>
          <p class="swiper-slide">samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample<br>samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample</p>
          <p class="swiper-slide">samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample<br>samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample</p>
          <p class="swiper-slide">samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample</p>
        </section>
      </div>
    <!-- 
to here
-->





      <img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/14x12.png?text=_" alt="▼" class="▼" width="14" />

      <div class="R-under">
        <div class="nbb">
          <h4 class="nb">sample</h4>
          <p class="nb-p">sample</p>
        </div>

        <div class="per">
          <h4 class="period">sample</h4>
          <p class="p-p">sample</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```